# How to represent a dot using pycairo

Tags: python, graphics, pycairo

I'm learning to use [Pycairo](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and I'm doing well till now, I can graph lines/bezier curves and soon, mathematical curves, I tried to express the point as a very tiny line but it doesn't work

I tried this too

```
context.move_to(5,5)
context.line_to(5,5)
```

I thought it may get me a dot but it was a line without length so it didn't appear, I can't seem to find a way to represent a dot, like I have a grid and I want to draw a dot like we do in maths classes, any suggestions for an approach?
so,

- I tried a line with a very tiny length (which didn't work)
- I tried a circle with zero radius

Till I realised that it's a circle with a tiny radius approaching zero, not zero.
The idea just escaped out of my mind

Comment: Try using the [`context.arc()`](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/context.html?highlight=curve_to#cairo.Context.arc) command to draw a full circle.

Comment: Not working too, you meant a radiusless circle right? didn't work

Comment: Yes, but be sure to set a non-zero `set_line_width()` first. You may also need to `set_line_join(ROUND)` beforehand, too.

Comment: I kept testing, doesn't work
can you provide me a code you tested to create a dot?

Comment: Sorry I don't have `pycario` installed. I was speaking from my experience as a Postscript® developer (and former Adobe employee). Perhaps giving the circular arc some infinitesimal radius would work so it's not quite zero.A last-resort workaround might be to create small rectangles using [`class cairo.Rectangle`](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/rectangle.html?highlight=rectangle#class-rectangle-tuple).

Comment: Another thought. Maybe you need to fill the current path after defining a (non-zero) radius circle via the [`fill()`](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/context.html?highlight=fill#cairo.Context.fill) drawing operator.

Comment: Thanks for discussion & reference, I got it with an arc with radius approaching zero , like 0.01 or 0.02, worked, I'll post the answer and close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How stupid of me, It's a filled circle of a radius approaching zero, Thanks martineau for helping.